# Is it ok to create EAGLContext for each thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, grand-central-dispatch

I want to do some work in my OpenGL ES project in concurrent GCD queues. Is it ok if to create EAGLContext for each thread? I'm going to do it with such way:

```
queue_ = dispatch_queue_create("test.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);


    dispatch_async(queue_, ^{
    NSMutableDictionary* threadDictionary = [[NSThread currentThread] threadDictionary];
    EAGLContext* context = threadDictionary[@"context"];
    if (!context) {
        context = /* creating EAGLContext with sharegroup */;
        threadDictionary[@"context"] = context;
    }

    if ([EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context]) {
        // rendering
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];
    }

});
```

If it is not correct what is the best practice to parallelize OpenGL rendering?

Answer (score 2):

Not only is it okay, this is the ***only*** way you can share OpenGL resources between multiple threads. Note that shareable resources are typically limited to resources that allocate memory (e.g. buffer objects, textures, shaders). They do not include objects that merely store state (e.g. the global state machine, Framebuffer Objects or Vertex Array Objects). But if you are considering modifying data that you are using for rendering, I would strongly advise against this.

Whenever GL has a command in the pipeline that has not finished, any attempt to modify a resource used by that command will block until the command finishes. A better solution would be to double-buffer your resources, have a copy you use for rendering and a separate copy you use for updating. When you finish updating, the next time your drawing thread uses that resource, have it swap the buffers used for updating and drawing. This will reduce the amount of time the driver has to synchronize your worker threads with the drawing thread.

Now, if you are suggesting here that you want to draw from multiple threads, then you should re-think your strategy. OpenGL generally does not benefit from issuing draw commands from multiple threads, it just creates a synchronization nightmare. Multi-threading is useful mostly for controlling VSYNC on multiple windows (probably not something you will ever encounter in ES) or streaming resource data in the background.

Comment: I'm going to use background only for texture loading. But I want to do it in concurrent queue(to load several textures at one moment). Is it ok for this case? Does EAGLContext have some memory overhead? Can I create EAGLContexts as many as I want?

Comment: The last question is implementation specific, but I doubt you would be able to create enough contexts to hit any sort of limit in any reasonably written software. As for the other two, if you create shared contexts then they will share the same memory for textures. And if all you are doing is loading **new** textures in the other threads, then this is a great use-case for shared contexts in multiple threads. If you were trying to update data in a texture that was already being used to draw something, then you would create a source of implicit driver synchronization that could hurt performance.

Comment: Practically speaking, if the multiple textures are loading from the same device (i.e. the same flash, the same hard drive, etc) you will probably not see much benefit to having multiple background threads simultaneously loading them, because ultimately they're going to serialize when doing I/O to a single device. If you're doing some sort of CPU-intensive post-processing, *maybe* there would be some benefit, but I would be surprised if multiple concurrent background loads outperformed serial loading of multiple textures on a single background thread.

Comment: @ipmcc: I doubt on an embedded device that you have the leisure of storing your resources uncompressed. Usually, that is the reason you would opt for multiple threads - competition for disk I/O will definitely be scheduled by the OS (hopefully FCFS in this case), but during the time one thread is waiting for I/O to finish another thread might be busy decompressing the resource it just finished reading. Though having said that, if the platform supports KTX or PVR compressed texture images natively you can definitely avoid all of this nonsense and stream the compressed image directly into GL.

Comment: Decompression may qualify as "CPU-intensive post-processing" but there's non-zero overhead involved in task scheduling, and decompression has to take more time than the overhead for it to be a win. If you really wanted to optimize, you'd serialize reads and parallelize decompression. Anyway, always be measuring. You can't improve what you don't measure.

Comment: I'm using the above method to load VBOs and textures in background threads, and am very rarely getting a crash on the `[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];` line. I'm creating all my background thread  contexts with the same share group. is there anything beyond whats in the above source code that I should be aware of? You mention it being rare to hit a cap on the number of contexts - is there a cap, even if rare?